# get windows startup program info

Tags: c++, windows, registry, startup

I like to get Windows startup programs info programmatically, such as the info shown when launch msconfig.exe. It would be nice if I can find msconfig.exe's source code. But I didn't find it yet. I know I can look at registry, HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.
But the problem is that the msconfig.exe shows the disabled startup program  and its disabled time, but the registry didn't show the disabled ones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For disabled start-up items, look for registry keys at:

// registry paths for MSConfig disabled startups

```
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig\startupfolder"
"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MSConfig\startupreg"
```

Other keys related to start-up items (excerpt from my code written long ago :)

```
// registry paths for startups
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_RUN                 = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_RUNONCE             = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce";

// registry paths for MSConfig disabled startups
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_MSCONFIG_STARTUPFOLDER = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupfolder";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_MSCONFIG_STARTUPREG    = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg";

const UnicodeString     STR_REG_IE_BHO              = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_IE_SEARCH_HOOKS     = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\URLSearchHooks";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_IE_TOOLBAR          = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Toolbar";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_IE_EXPLORER_BARS    = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Explorer Bars";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_IE_EXTENSIONS       = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Extensions";
const UnicodeString     STR_REG_CLSID               = L"SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID";
```